# Preview label written in Eltron Programming Language EPL?

Tags: zebra-printers, epl

I have code produced by our proprietry system in the Eltron Programming Language:
This is sent to Eltron/Zebra label printers to be printed.

Is there some kind of software that would allow me to interpret this code to do some form of 'print preview'?

I am considering developing a way to convert this into an image or even postscript pdf, but I am struggling with how to do the barcodes (the lines starting in B is for barcodes).

```
N
Q296,24
R132,0
S2
D9
ZB
A3,2,0,3,1,1,N,"RB10SS5"
B3,22,0,2C,2,4,35,N,"391369840"
A3,60,0,3,1,1,N,"391369840"
A3,80,0,3,1,1,N,"Testing"
A3,100,0,4,1,1,N,"Serology"
A3,130,0,1,1,1,N,"SSTORE"
A185,16,0,1,1,1,N,"17 Mar"
A185,35,0,1,1,1,N,"SEROL"
A185,51,0,1,1,1,N,"0.50"
B400,208,0,2C,2,4,40,N,"391369840"
A400,254,0,2,1,1,N,"391369840"
P1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zebra doesn't provide software to do this for EPL labels, but if you have a ZPL/EPL printer and convert the labels to ZPL, you can use the printer's web page to view the label once its on the printer

Comment: Hi, If I dont have an actual printer with me. But installed the printer driver instead. Is there anyway for me to access the printer's web page?

Answer (score -10):

```
I8,A,001


Q200,024
q448
rN
S4
D7
ZT
JF
O
R24,0
f100N

I8,
A,001



Q200,
024
q448
rN
S4
D7
ZT
JF
O
R24,
0
f100
N

B380,179,2,1,2,6,40,N,"<parcel_name>"

A355,107,2,4,1,1,N,"<model> <color> <clarity> Cut:<cut>"

A355,80,2,4,1,1,N,"Dpt:<depth>  Tbl:<table_size>"

A355,54,2,4,1,1,N,"Pol:<polish>  Sym:<symmetry>  Fl:<flouresence>"

A355,27,2,4,1,1,N,"<gemology_institute_name> <certificate_number>"

A355,134,2,4,1,1,N,"<parcel_name_formatted>     <carat>"

P1
```

Comment: Hi, this is a pretty large amount of code, so it would help if you would include some description of how the code works to solve the question being asked here.